# How to achieve Provider.select behaviour using built in InheritedWidget like MediaQuery?

Tags: performance, flutter, inherited-widget

In my chat app every message depends on MediaQuery (font scaling). When keyboard is appear on Android 11+ then bottom insets in MediaQuery are animated from 0 to keyboard height. It cause unwanted rebuilds of all messages, but they depends only from font scaling. With Provider library I can use method `select` for this case. How to achieve same result with MediaQuery?

Comment: Can you provide the code

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code provided in the question, I'll try to help based on the question description. I see multiple potential issues here.

1. The `viewInsets` animation of `MediaQuery` is probably **not** what's causing the rebuild.

One might think the dependence on MediaQuery's `textScaleFactor` is the cause of rebuilds whenever `MediaQuery` changes, but I'm willing to bet that, even if you remove the dependency and just simply return an empty `Container`, it would still rebuild during the keyboard collapse animation.

2. So what's causing the rebuilds? Probably the fact that the app area expanded/shrank due to keyboards popping up.

For example, the total height of a `Scaffold` would actually shrink, when a keyboard is visible. If you don't want this, you can set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` for it, like so:

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  // ...
```

3. You can access text scale factor much earlier in the widget tree.

If you really want to only get the text scale factor of MediaQuery, you can access it from much earlier in the widget tree, and save it as a variable, and pass it down however you like (provider, etc):

```
final scaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
print(scaleFactor);
```

4. You can remove `viewInsets` from `MediaQuery` if you really want to.

If you want to remove `viewInsets` (or set it to a fixed value), you can override it by inserting another `MediaQuery` on the tree:

```
return MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
    viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
  ),
  child: Container( /* always zero insets */ ),
);
```

5. Rebuilding shouldn't be a problem.

Lastly, Flutter widgets should be prepared to be rebuilt at any time and shouldn't cause any issues. So I assume you are only noticing your widgets being rebuilt because Flutter Inspector, or you added a `print` in the build method, and noticed a bunch of prints in the console. I wouldn't worry too much about it unless you are actually experiencing REAL performance issues. However, if your widgets don't behave properly when rebuilt at "unexpected times", you should fix that, because Flutter WILL rebuild your widgets all the time, not just when the keyboard is collapsed :D

Comment: Removing `MediaQuery.of(context)` fix the problem and page has no more extra rebuilds.    My question is - how to `select` and react to concrete InheritedWidget changes. `Provider` implementation has this ability, but standard widgets like MediaQuery - are not. Maybe I can wrap in Provider or something else..

Comment: @NickolaySavchenko You are correct that InheritedWidget do not have `select` feature. So it looks like maybe your situation falls under case #3 from my answer?